# python xarray.sel unstable for xr.dataArray of strings

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a xr.Dataset named IDB, which has a DataArray named "affiliations", composed of strings:

```
IDB.affiliations
<xarray.DataArray 'affiliations' (stations: 92)>
array(['Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia',
       'Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia',
       'Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia',
       'Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia',
       ..............
```

After I select a subset using Dataset.sel() I get:

```
IDB = IDB.sel({'stations':a_subset_of_stations})

IDB.affiliations
<xarray.DataArray 'affiliations' (stations: 24)>
array([array('Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia', dtype=object),
       array('Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia', dtype=object),
       array('Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia', dtype=object),
       array('Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia', dtype=object),
       ..................
```

So, instead of an array of strings, I get an array of arrays that contain strings! This prevents me from saving this into a netcdf..

IDB.to_netcdf(pathOut,mode='w',engine='netcdf4')

ValueError: unable to infer dtype on variable 'affiliations'; xarray cannot serialize arbitrary Python objects

Comment: Please make your problem one that can be reproducible. You should provide code that someone else could run and produce the problem, instead of a small chunk of what you have done

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the whole code

Comment: You don't need to share the whole code, just enough that someone can understand the problem. For example, what is `a_subset_of_stations`? Don't rely on people correctly guessing what your code is doing

Answer (score 0):

Exploring this error, I found that it disappeared if I occasionally explicitly accessed the values of the corresponding dataarrays.

What I did to make it work is accessing on purpose all the values of the datarrays within the dataset, and the error stopped being reproduced:

```
## xarray BUG
for variable in list(IDB.variables.keys()):
    spare = IDB[variable].values

## Now, apply sel...
IDB = IDB.sel({'stations':a_subset_of_stations})
IDB.affiliations

<xarray.DataArray 'affiliations' (stations: 24)>
array(['Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia',
       'Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia',
       'Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia',
       'Instituto_Argentino_de_Oceanografia',
```

Hope this is useful for someone...